# Perl XML::Writer prints bad character

Tags: xml, perl, xmlwriter

I am using [XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aWriter) and I have this code:

```
foreach $param (@{$fce->{"params"}}){
  $i++;
  print $param . ",";
  $writer->emptyTag( 'param', number => $i, type => $param );
}
```

This is output of XML::Writer:

```
<param number="1" type="const enum eDebugLevels" />
<param number="2" type="const char   &#9;&#9;*  const" />
```

But output of that print is:

```
const enum eDebugLevels,const char       *  const,
```

Why are there the `&#9;`? I really don't want them (and I need spaces to stay as they are). Thank you

Comment: Those are encoded tabs. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: I would have this check for equality with pattern solution and there are that tabs "coded".

Comment: Did you look at the [XML::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/~josephw/XML-Writer-0.615/Writer.pm) documentation? Perhaps there is an option to disable encoding, however I don't think that's a good idea at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#9;` is a tab, so for any XML parser `"const char   &#9;&#9;*  const"` will be parsed as `"const char   \t\t*  const"`. If you have a problem with tabs, then you need to pre-process your output, it's not XML::Writer's job to do this.